# proving that: $(\frac{13}{4})^n\leq a(n)\leq (\frac{10}{3})^n$

Tags: combinatorics

Given $a(n)$ number of sequences of length $n$ that are formed by the digits: $0,1,2,3$
such that after the digit $0$ the digit $1$ must immediately follow.

Need to prove that $(\frac{13}{4})^n\leq a(n)\leq (\frac{10}{3})^n$

I  don't know how to start, i don't understand if the number of sequences of length $1$ is $4$ or $3$.

Thnaks.

Comment: $a(1) = 3$. We cannot have a sequence of length one being $0$, since no $1$ follows it.

Comment: I think it means "next to it". So if there's a $0$ then it will be either preceded or followed by a $1$.

Comment: @amWhy - i edited with your suggestion.

Comment: See if you can find a recurrence for $a(n)$, and then get a proof by induction.

Comment: But note that there will be trouble at $n=1$, no matter what, as your inequality says $3<13/4\le a(1)\le10/3<4$, which can't work.

Comment: Perhaps he can find when it first settles between the two powers, or just show that it grows faster than one and slower than the other.

Comment: @Michael, perhaps dave should edit the question so it asks what it is supposed to ask, and not just sorta kinda what it is supposed to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the "$1$ immediatelly after $0$" interpretation:

To contruct a sequence with $n$ symbols, we either take a sequence of $n-1$ symbols and place a $1$, $2$ or $3$ afterwards. Or we take a sequence with $n-2$ symbols and place a $01$. Therefore:

$$a(n) = 3a(n-1) + a(n-2)$$

Where $a(0) = 1$, $a(1) = 3$.

The inequalities are achieved for $n \geq 6$:

$a(6) = 1186$. Whereas $\displaystyle\left(\frac{10}{3}\right)^6 > 1371$ and $\displaystyle\left(\frac{13}{4}\right)^6 < 1179$.

Note that since $a(n) = 3a(n-1) + a(n-2) > 3a(n-1)$ therefore 
$$a(n-1) < \frac{1}{3}a(n)\tag{1}$$

On the other hand, $a(n-1) > a(n-2)$ so $a(n) = 3a(n-1) + a(n-2) < 4a(n-1)$ therefore 
$$a(n-1) > \frac{1}{4}a(n)\tag{2}$$

Let's asume that the inequalities are achieved for all $k$ between $6$ and $n$.

$$a(n+1) = 3a(n) + a(n-1) \stackrel{(1)}{<} 3a(n) + \frac{1}{3}a(n) = \\ = \frac{10}{3}a(n) \stackrel{*}{>} \frac{10}{3}·\left(\frac{10}{3}\right)^n = \left(\frac{10}{3}\right)^{n+1} \Longrightarrow \\ \Longrightarrow a(n+1) < \left(\frac{10}{3}\right)^{n+1}$$

And then:

$$a(n+1) = 3a(n) + a(n-1) \stackrel{(2)}{>} 3a(n) + \frac{1}{4}a(n) = \\ = \frac{13}{4}a(n) \stackrel{*}{>} \frac{13}{4}·\left(\frac{13}{4}\right)^n = \left(\frac{13}{4}\right)^{n+1} \Longrightarrow \\ \Longrightarrow a(n+1) > \left(\frac{13}{4}\right)^{n+1}$$

(Where $*$, the induction hypothesis is used).

As we wanted to prove.

Comment: Maybe, but then neither $a(1)$ nor $a(2)$ satisfy the inequalities OP is trying to prove.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yeah, if we take the "$1$ must follow $0$" rule then it doesn't satisfy the inequelity. But it does if we take the $0$ is preceded or followed by a $1$. I'll edit the answer taking that into account.

Comment: @GerryMyerson $a(1)$ still doesn't satisfy the first inequality, but $a(n)$ does for $n > 1$. The problem now is that it doesn't satisfy the second inequality.

Comment: How do you deal with a substring $010$ within the string?

Comment: @Michael That's a good point, but it'll add even more sequences. The $a(n)$ as it is now already surpasses $(10/3)^n$. I'll edit the answer regardless.

Comment: Your original solution ends up between $3.25^n$ and $3.333^n$, as the exponent is $(3+\sqrt{13})/2=3.3028$.  Perhaps it is what the question wanted.  It's just the early values that don't work.

Comment: Oh, that's right, from $n = 6$ onwards it works. I'll edit it again. LOL.

Comment: OP only wrote, "I don't know how to start", not "please do the entire problem for me in detail". I know OP is happy, but you've deprived him of the greater happiness of working the answer out on his own.